# Is there a way to see the most recent Mercurial revision for each file in a directory?

Tags: mercurial

When you do `hg log` on a file, only the revisions that underwent  changes are listed. I'd like to see what the most recent revision for all of the files in a directory is. (Think `hg blame` at a file level rather than a line level.)

I had thought that `hg log -l 1 *` might work, but it just shows the most recent revision across all of the files.

Here's the kind of output I'd like to see:

```
> hg blame --files
foo: 15
bar: 2
baz: 15
README: 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another alternative is to use a combination of `hg status` and `hg log`, like this:

```
for FILE in $(hg status -nA); do
    hg log -l1 --template '{rev}\t' "$FILE"
    echo $FILE
done
```

Answer (score 1):

I *suspect* that if you want to use `hg` directly to do this, you'll need to write an extension (but I'm by no means an expert here). But would something like this work, if you're willing to use a script?

```
for x in *; do
    highest=`hg blame "$x" 2>/dev/null | cut -d : -f 1 | sort -nr | head -n1`
    if [ "$highest" ]; then echo "$x: $highest" ; fi
done
```

The obvious downside here is that this is pretty slow.

Comment: Rather than using `hg blame`, you could use `hg parents <file> --template "{rev}\n"` to find the most rev where the file was changed.